# Joi validate if the number is a multiple of x

Tags: node.js, validation, joi

Current validation:

```
const myPacket = Joi.object({
  cost: Joi.number().precision(2).required()
})
```

Here, how do I check if my `cost` field is a multiple of `0.25` or not? So, for example, valid values for `cost` would be 1.25, 2.5, 2.25, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom method and write your own logic there https://github.com/sideway/joi/blob/master/API.md#anycustommethod-description

example

```js
const Joi = require('joi')

const myCustomValidation = (value, helpers) => {
  if (typeof value !== 'number') return helpers.error('any.invalid')
  
  if (parseFloat(value*4) % 1 === 0) {
    // your logic above
    return value
  } else return helpers.error('any.invalid')
}

const schema = Joi.object({
  customField: Joi.number().custom(myCustomValidation, 'my custom validation description')
})

schema.validate({customField: 1.25})
schema.validate({customField: 1.251})
```

Comment: Do we need `parseFloat` if it's already `Joi.number()` ?

Comment: Also, with the above code custom error message does not show up.

Comment: @YetAnotherBot good point about parseFloat. also see this if you want custom message https://github.com/sideway/joi/blob/master/API.md#extensions